# Windows 8.1 Mouse and Keyboard lose connection during boot

Tags: windows, usb, keyboard, mouse

I was building a new computer so I moved a couple hard drives (not the windows 8.1 boot drive, though I did move a Windows 10 boot drive) from my old desktop computer.  One of the next times I tried to boot the old Windows 8.1 computer, it had a solid connection to the keyboard and mouse at first - but then it lost connection by the time it got to the Windows login screen.

It now consistently loses the connection.  The keyboard and mouse are wired. I have tried multiple ports without success.

The old computer had issues with bad connections in the front USB ports, but the back USB ports have always been solid.

The motherboard is a MSI Intel Z97 LGA 1150.  The only USB devices it is currently using are the keyboard and mouse.

How can I get the Windows 8.1 computer to boot?

Comment: Since I imagine you opened up the old computer and did some work inside, it might be a bad connection. Open it up again and press all connectors. It might also be a new hardware problem.

Comment: Maybe. I only removed a couple hard drives. Didn't touch the motherboard.  No new hardware.